# Next.JS + AMP CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, next.js, amp-html

I'm having trouble with AMP and CSS in Next.js. In my head component I have:

```
<Head>
    <style amp-custom>{`
        // CSS Here
    `}</style>
</Head>
```

In the HTML source it shows up as `<style amp-custom=""></style><style>(CSS Here)</style>`

In the console I get this error: `The mandatory attribute 'amp-custom' is missing in tag 'style amp-custom (transformed)'.`

How can I work with AMPHTML's rules on CSS and Next both? Every other method I've tried (such as importing from a file using @zeit/next-sass) causes the CSS to not be rendered at all. This is the only working version I've found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...It has to be: `<style jsx>...</style>`. Very dumb mistake that I've been looking for workarounds on all day. :/

Comment: I notice that adding 'global' tag to 'style jsx' element or not is the same. All style elements go to amp-custom style tag, because it can only be one per page. Official source: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<Head>
    <style
      amp-custom=""
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `
          amp-img {
            border: 1px solid black;
          }
        `,
      }}
    ></style>
</Head>
```

Comment: Thanks, finnaly after reafding for hours, thank you
I was actually doing this and it was not working
<style>{this.props.styleTags[0].props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML.__html}</style>
or 
<style amp-custom="">{this.props.styleTags[0].props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML.__html}</style>

Comment: Yours is the only working solution I found

Answer (score 4):

As of Sept 2020, I've been having this issue too. I'm new at this, but with no help from the official tutorials. I did find a workaround.

First, I want to point out a couple of things from Next.js that they tell you.

1. non-AMP page styles are usually placed in _document.js from the next.js example.

> ```
> </Head>
> <style jsx global>{ reset }</style>
> <style jsx global>{ globals }</style>
> <body>
>   <Main />
>   <NextScript />
>  </body>
> ```

2. They mention in the tutorial to put `<style amp-custom>`. They don't say where, but it should be within the `<Head></Head>` of index.js (or whatever .js file for individual pages) OR _document.js for every page.

Ok, sounds good, BUT it's partially wrong!

**I will explain what I found it does when turn on amp pages on in Next.JS.**

So on an individual page, such as index.js, you need to this code at the top:

> ```
> export const config = {
>   amp: true,
> }
> ```

Then you have to put this in the return function:

> const isAmp = useAmp()

Standard instructions from the tutorial. Now AMP is turned on, here's what happens:

1. Anything in `<style amp-custom>` is turned into a `<style>`
2. anything that is in `<style jsx>` is turned into a `<style amp-custom>` tag.
3. In addition to #2, it injects a unique random index that ruins any css code in that gets put into the generated `<style amp-custom>` tag.

> ```
>  <style amp-custom>.jsx-2373233908{/* your CSS code that you put in <style jsx> from before */}</style>
> ```

and that .jsx-########### throws a "/  error  CSS syntax error in tag 'style amp-custom' - incomplete declaration." when you try to compile.

Is this opposite and odd behavior. YES. I don't get why it does it, but I'm a newb.

So my workaround goes like this:

1. Install your CSS framework package or put your CSS file into the styles folder (let's say located at : ./styles/styles.css)
2. I also add raw loader from your terminal window. Because I like to put my css in a file, not type it inlined with the code. Let's be realistic, you're going to separate CSS and you'll need to load that file in.

> npm install raw-loader --save-dev

3. Load the CSS in your _document.js (here's my whole _document.js). I use "}" and "{" with fixCSS to escape the .jsx-########### and the injected code magically disappears.

> ```
> import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
>
> import styleCSS from '!!raw-loader!../styles/styles.css';
> const fixCSS = `}${styleCSS}{`;
>
> class MyDocument extends Document {
>   static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
>     const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
>     return { ...initialProps }
>   }
>
>   render() {
>     return (
>       <Html lang="en">
>       <Head>
>       </Head>
>       <style jsx>{`
>       ${fixCSS}
>     ` }</style>
>         <body>
>           <Main />
>           <NextScript />
>         </body>
>       </Html>
>     )
>   }
> }
> export default MyDocument
> ```

That's it. Now your imported CSS is shown on AMP pages. Remember this is for sept 2020 using these packages in my package.json:

> ```
>   "dependencies": {
>     "amp": "^0.3.1",
>     "next": "^9.5.3-canary.25",
>     "next-env": "^1.1.1",
>     "react": "^16.13.1",
>     "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
> },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
>     "now": "^19.2.0",
>     "raw-loader": "^4.0.1"
>   },
> ```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for my use case of having a specific amp file in the `/pages` dir

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<style jsx amp-custom>
`
  ... my css
`
</style>
```

I just tested it out and it worked okay. Not the best approach, NextJS should document the ways to add css in somewhere.

Comment: amp-custom tag in style element as no effect so ever. it works without it, so it is redundant with @Ethan answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
const ampStyle = `h1{color:red;}`

<style jsx>{ampStyle}</style>
```