# AMP style amp-custom returns empty on HTML; results in validation error

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I'm using AMP on NextJs and am trying to insert  in my head tag. I managed to get it into the head tag but the rendered html returns an empty

`<style amp-custom></style>`

and instead booted all of my minified style css out into a separate style tag without the attribute 'amp-custom', thats why the validation did not pass.

Here is how I did it;

```
    <Head>
      {isAmp ? (
        <>
          <script
            async
            custom-element="amp-carousel"
            src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"
          ></script>
          <style amp-custom>
            {`amp-img.nav-logo{margin:10px;margin-top:13px}.bg-primary-color{background-color:#ff4e4e}.bg-white{background-color:#fff}.px-3{padding-right:.75rem;padding-left:.75rem}.pb-3{padding-bottom:.75rem}.p-4{padding:1rem}.shadow-xl{box-shadow:0 20px 25px -5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,.04)}.detail-container{margin:0 auto;margin-top:16px;margin-bottom:16px;padding-right:16px;padding-left:16px}`}
            {/* {`${Global} ${OutletDetail} ${InfoCardStyle}`} */}
          </style>
        </>
      ) : (
        undefined
      )}
      <SEO />
    </Head>
```

and here is what is rendered;
[image: html_console]

Any advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have the exact answer for your problem, but I did find this post where a couple of possible solutions are discussed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482125/next-js-amp-css. If I were you, I would try to include the stylings from a variable or a file (e.g. https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/style_pages)